# Creating a new TemporaryDirectory object doesn't create the directory

Tags: python

Case 1:

The directory 'C:\Users\jim\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9lf9xalc' is created.

```
In [1]:
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
temp_dir = TemporaryDirectory()
temp_dir.name

Out [1]:
'C:\\Users\\jim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp9lf9xalc'
```

Case 2:

The directory 'C:\Users\jim\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpm861vgbn' is NOT created.

```
In [2]:
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
temp_dir = TemporaryDirectory().name
temp_dir

Out [2]:
'C:\\Users\\jim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpm861vgbn'
```

I don't understand why in Case 2 the directory is not created.

The source code of TemporaryDirectory is as follows. It's located at ..\Anaconda3\envs\my_env\Lib\tempfile.py

```
class TemporaryDirectory(object):
    """Create and return a temporary directory.  This has the same
    behavior as mkdtemp but can be used as a context manager.  For
    example:

        with TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
            ...

    Upon exiting the context, the directory and everything contained
    in it are removed.
    """

    def __init__(self, suffix=None, prefix=None, dir=None):
        self.name = mkdtemp(suffix, prefix, dir)
        self._finalizer = _weakref.finalize(
            self, self._cleanup, self.name,
            warn_message="Implicitly cleaning up {!r}".format(self))

    @classmethod
    def _cleanup(cls, name, warn_message):
        _shutil.rmtree(name)
        _warnings.warn(warn_message, ResourceWarning)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{} {!r}>".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.name)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.name

    def __exit__(self, exc, value, tb):
        self.cleanup()

    def cleanup(self):
        if self._finalizer.detach():
            _shutil.rmtree(self.name)
```

Comment: I suspect that it's because of the `_weakref.finalize`... Once your variable goes out of scope (which is immediately in the second case), your directory cleans itself up.

Comment: You should notice the first case delete itself when you close the interpreter normally, but possibly not when you kill it with a system-level abort like `kill -9`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: With just one process, it’s utterly impossible to `unlink` or `rmdir` _anything_ on `SIGKILL`.

Comment: @DavisHerring. Hence my suspicion that it wouldn't be possible :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Good—but there is a difference between “possibly not” and “not possibly”!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the doc string says, you’re supposed to use `with`:

```
with TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
  loc=tmpdir.name
  # ...
```

Then it knows when you’re done with the directory and removes it for you.  As a backup, it also cleans up when the `TemporaryDirectory` object is *destroyed*, issuing a `ResourceWarning` because that behavior and its timing cannot be guaranteed across Python implementations.

This backup happens immediately (for CPython) in your second case, since you kept no reference to the `TemporaryDirectory`, so the directory is removed as soon as it is created.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `.name()` on the method causes the original class to go out of scope since it returns a string, which triggers the cleanup.

Consider:

```
temp_dir = TemporaryDirectory().name
#                             ^ executes, but is now out of scope
```

vs.

```
temp_dir_ref = TemporaryDirectory()
print(temp_dir_ref.name)
#                   ^ ok!
```

To fix it, assign the name after the class is assigned as in your first example.

If the only thing you want a directory to be created and just have the string, you can call the lower-level `mkdtemp` function, which simply creates the directory and returns a string.

It's on you (or, possibly the operating system depending on where the temporary directory lands) to clean it up.

```
import shutil
from tempfile import mkdtemp


temp_dir = mkdtemp()
try:
    ...some stuff...
finally:
    shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
```